# git clone private repo with --mount=type=ssh does not work

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

In my terminal, this does work:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:X/X.git
```

I want to clone a private repository from my Dockerfile. This does not work. Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR app

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:X/X.git
```

Error:

```
 > [builder 5/8] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:X/X.git:
#0 0.086 Cloning into 'X'...
#0 0.548 Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.121.3' to the list of known hosts.
#0 0.818 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#0 0.827 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#0 0.827 
#0 0.827 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#0 0.827 and the repository exists.
```

Strange, since it worked with the exact same terminal session when I directly use git cloen.

How can I clone private repositories in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Does the ssh-key you generate inside the docker container exist as an authorized key in GitHub? I guess it works from your terminal because your ssh key is already on github, but the new key you generate everytime is not on github.

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` collects *host* keys, used to verify that GitHub.com is who it claims to be. It does not collect keys used to authenticate with GitHub when you run `git clone`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that method described in "[Docker - Using ssh in buildsDocker - Using ssh in builds](https://pyojuncode-github-io.translate.goog/Docker-using-ssh-in-builds/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)"

But the Dockerfile you are describing is preceded with:

> A feature of Buildkit, supported since Docker 18.09 SSH forwarding, allows you to easily use your existing SSH credentials during Docker builds.
>
> First of all, it is necessary to register the SSH key to be used in the SSH-agent before building.
>
> ### Run ssh-agent
>
> ```bash
> $ eval $(ssh-agent)
> > Agent pid 28899
> # Check 
> $ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
> > /tmp/ssh-gE3XpbSmJuAc/agent.28898
> ```
>
> ### Add ssh key to ssh-agent
>
> $ ssh-add /home/junpyo/.ssh/pyojuncode_ssh/pyojuncode_ssh
>
> Afterwards configure dockerfile to use SSH forwarding.

So make sure you have added the right key (the one whose public key is registered to your GitHub account) is added to a local agent, under the same account as the one running the `docker build`, with BuildKit.